# Is there a standard for capitalization of Android app menuitems?

Tags: android, menu, language, app, capitalization

For menuitems in Android apps, is there a standard for capitalizing (or not capitalizing) each word within each menuitem?

For example:

- Open
- View log
- Exit

versus:

- Open
- View Log
- Exit

Answer (score 4):

Material design can be considered to be a standard when it comes to anything on Android app design. [Material design on capitalization](https://material.google.com/style/writing.html#writing-capitalization-punctuation):

> Use sentence-style caps for all titles, headings, labels, menu items – any place that considered for “Title-Style Caps.”

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe it's just me, but the erroneous grammar in Google's document adds to the confusion.  What does help is their example recommending the use us of "Search settings" instead of "Search Settings".  It is ironic that the section of their style guide pertaining to language has such a blatant language error.  That's Google for you.

Answer (score 0):

Android app menu items should use [***sentence case***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization#Sentence_case):

> ### Capitalization
>
> Use sentence-style capitalization for all UI strings: “Words to live
>   by.”

**Source:** [Writing Style: Formatting text](http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/writing.html) on [androiddocs.com](http://www.androiddocs.com/index.html).